# Change the brightness of the carousel's background (bootstrap)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm using bootstrap, and I added a carousel by this way. The carousel works fine.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
</ol>
<div class="carousel-inner " role="listbox">
    <div class="item active car1">
        <div class="container carou">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p class="titreCarousel">Example headline.<p>
                <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                <a class="lienCarousel text-uppercase" href="#">On vous explique en vidéo</a>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

 ... x4 almost the same


<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

To add the images in background, I'm using the property `background: url(../images/bg-5.jpg) no-repeat center;` and `background-size : cover;` because with the `<img>`, the image is deformed so I need to use the property "cover" of the background.

Now, I want to increase the brightness of this background but my problem is when I try to add `filter: brightness(50%);`, the texts inherit of this property too.

The css that I tried :

```
.carou
{
    filter: brightness(50%);
    -webkit-filter: brightness(50%);
    -moz-filter: brightness(50%);
    -o-filter: brightness(50%);
    -ms-filter: brightness(50%);
}
```

Can someone help me please ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: instead of filtering the whole `container`, try to add a `pseudo element` on `.item` and implement th `filter` on that, that's how you would avoid blurry effect on texts with `z-index`.

Comment: @FarzadYZ Thanks, but the background is on the element `car1` so it's for the whole container. So I don't really understand what you want me to do :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you could separate your background image and info into sibling divs ad just use a bit of CSS to position them accordingly, like this...

HTML

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active car1">
       <div class="container carou">
            <!-- This div has your background image -->
        </div>
        <div class="car1-info">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
               <p class="titreCarousel">Example headline.<p>
               <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non 
          mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
               <a class="lienCarousel text-uppercase" href="#">On vous explique en vidéo</a>
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.car1{
    position: relative
}
.car1-info{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:1em
}
.carou
{
    height:200px; /* or whatever height your banner is */
    background:url(/* your img url */);
    background-size:cover;

    filter: brightness(50%);
    -webkit-filter: brightness(50%);
    -moz-filter: brightness(50%);
    -o-filter: brightness(50%);
    -ms-filter: brightness(50%);
}
```

Comment: As you said, I separeted the background with the text and it works, Some things in your css didn't work like the `position`. But I resolved it and now it works, thanks a lot !

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps that will help you.

`JSFiddle`

> Obs:
>   I think this is what [Farzad YZ](http:///users/2784512/farzad-yz) meant